# Why does a migrated question appear to have no answers?

Tags: support, user-interface

The question [How do I resolve an “expected expression before 'unsigned'” error? [migrated]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126210/how-do-i-resolve-an-expected-expression-before-unsigned-error) appears right now on the [active questions list](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) as having zero answers, and as having been posted by me, while in fact it has 6 answers and it was NOT posted by me. If you look at it at on the [newest questions list](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) it appears as posted by the correct poster, but still as having zero answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In the active page and the homepage, the avatar is of the one that last modified the question, not necessarily the original asker. Modified can mean a number of things, an edit to the question or any of its answers, a new answer, closing the question, making it [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) (automatically or by hand), etc<sup>(?)</sup>.

On the other hand, when visiting the newest page you are explicitly asking for the questions to be ordered on when they where asked, so it makes a little bit more sense<sup>(?)</sup> to show the original asker's avatar.

As for the answers count, the question has found a new home at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583017/how-do-i-resolve-an-expected-expression-before-unsigned-error), and all its answers followed the migration, so essentially zero answers here. They exist there now, and not here. The same goes with any downvotes to the question, they don't follow the migration, kind of a fresh start.

That's the way it is. I don't necessarily like it.

Answer (score 2):

The question was migrated to Stack Overflow: when a question is migrated, all of its answers on the source site will be deleted and reposted on the destination site.

So, if you look at [the question right now on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126210/how-do-i-resolve-an-expected-expression-before-unsigned-error?noredirect=1), it really does have 0 answers, and both the active questions list and the newest questions list are accurately reporting that fact. You can find the answers (including yours) [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583017/how-do-i-resolve-an-expected-expression-before-unsigned-error).

Now, why one shows you're the last poster and one doesn't:

- the active questions list is sorted by the last time the question was modified. Since you were the last person to modify the question (by posting an answer), you're listed.
- the newest questions list is sorted by when the question was first posted. Since you're not the person who asked the question, you're not listed.